# Getting "hour out of range" on time.Parse(layout, value) in Go

Tags: go, time

I am getting the error `hour out of range` while trying to parse a timestamp string with the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0530"
    timeStr := "2020-05-23 22:55:51 +0530"
    t, tErr := time.Parse(layout, timeStr)
    log.Printf("Layout: %s", layout)
    log.Printf("Time (string): %s", timeStr)
    log.Printf("Time (time.Time): %s", t.String())
    if tErr != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: %s", tErr.Error())
    }
}
```

Playground: https://goplay.space/#SIWJWKduPQg

Repeat of / Similar to: [Hour out of range on time.parse in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876621/hour-out-of-range-on-time-parse-in-golang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the proper format constant for parsing.

For Numeric time zone offsets in https://golang.org/src/time/format.go

```
Numeric time zone offsets format as follows:
    -0700  ±hhmm
    -07:00 ±hh:m
    -07    ±hh
```

Here for parsing `±hhmm` you should use exact format `-0700`.
So use `-0700` instead of `+0530` in parsing format

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700"
```

Comment: Now it is giving me an extra `+0530` in the time.String() [https://goplay.space/#MZyh2hAZrck](https://goplay.space/#MZyh2hAZrck)

Comment: Generally String print like "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST" timezone offset and timezone name, in your case there is no timezone name so outputs the offset twice means in place of timezone name . Ref: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The timezone offset in the layout should be `-0700` not `+0530`

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700"
```